# Пушкинский Балда

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Интересно, а вот Балда - это имя или прозвище? Сейчас "балдой" называют недалекого, неумного человека, но пушкиский Балда, наоборот, показан находчивым и сообразительным. Тогда почему - Балда?
Сейчас пришла в голову мысль, что слово "балда" может происходить от тюркского "балта" - "топор".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В современном русском языке слово **балда** имеет два значения: 1) бран., прост. "бестолковый, глупый человек"; 2) спец. "тяжелый молот". В говорах *балдА* - "долговязый и неуклюжий дурень", *балдА* и *бАлда* - "тяжелый набалдашник", "шишка", "дубина"; ср. *балодка* - "кузнечный одноручный молоток" (Даль). Слово встречается и в других славянских языках приблизительно с теми же значениями: просторечное бранное слово и некое орудие определенной формы. В значении "дубинка" или "шишка, утолщение у дубины", или "молот" слово *балда* (иногда в форме *болда*) известно с XVII в. А значение "глупец" вторичное (видимо, непосредственно из "долговязый, неуклюжий человек", а оно - из "палка", "дубинка"; ср. *дубина, чурбан, колода* и т.п. с бранным значением).

У Пушкина **Балда** - личное имя (Историко-этимологический словарь П.Я. Черных), и герой с этим именем вовсе не "балда", но, возможно, под влиянием многочисленных сказок о глупцах пушкинского Балду стали смешивать с дурнем народной сказки.

Само слово неславянское, надо полагать, тюркское. Фасмер считает, что слово **балда** в русском языке происходит из диал. формы тюрк. balta, тур. balta "топор". Другие производят от тур. baldak "кольцо, эфес сабли" (ср. производное "набалдашник").